# Intersection of Convex Sets: Simple Topology/Geometry

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-geometry

So I have a simple question regarding convex sets and their intersection.

Let $\{ X_i \}_{i \in I}$ be a collection of open convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $X_i \cap X_j \cap X_k \neq \emptyset$ for all $i,j,k \in I$.

Does it then necessarily follow that $\bigcap_{i \in I} X_i \neq \emptyset$?

If it does, what is the proof, and if it does not, what is a good counterexample?

I look forward to your answers.

Comment: In what context did you encounter this problem?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Question no. 2 of section 1.2 of Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*. If the statement holds true, then the answer is trivial. If the answer is false, then I'm going to have to come up with some other way of solving it. Either way, it seemed to me like pertinent information to keep at the back of one's head regardless.

Comment: First I spent some time trying to prove it entirely in terms of intersection. That turned out to be a bit of a waste, since I eventually realized that there was nothing in my assumption about the $X_i$'s I was working with that necessitated them being convex. This made me think I probably need to use some argument about straight lines and all points of those lines being in the intersection. Then things just started getting messy, and I became unsure as to whether my approach was even correct in the first place. That's when I appealed for help.

Comment: Try a nested construction, e.g. The sequence (n,\infty) where n is a natural number consist of open convex sets yet The total intersection is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For finite $I$ it’s true in $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^2$, thanks to [Helly’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem), but without compactness it can fail for infinite $I$ even in $\Bbb R$, as **user587399** pointed out in the comments. (We can, for instance, let $I_n=(0,2^{-n})$.) It also fails in $\Bbb R^m$ for $m\ge 3$. In $\Bbb R^3$, for instance, start with four points on the unit sphere located at the vertices of a regular tetrahedron. The edge length of the tetrahedron is $\sqrt{8/3}$, so the distance from a vertex to the centre of any face of which it is a vertex is $\frac{2\sqrt2}3$, so choose $r\in\left(\frac{2\sqrt2}3,1\right)$; then any three of the open balls of radius $r$ centred at the vertices of the tetrahedron intersect, but the intersection of all four is empty.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! Argh! That is most annoying! Suppose I have no choice but to use proof by induction then on the rest of the exercise in Hatcher.

Comment: @StormyTeacup: You’re very welcome. (And I think that we all know that feeling!)